# Shortening a string in Haskell with a condition

Tags: string, haskell

Chomp will take the longest amount of repeated characters from a string and one will limit this to 9, e.g. if given the string "aaaaabbbcc" , the answer would be "aaaaa"

I need to define a function, runs, which will do a similiar thing but it will put the string into separate lists, e.g. if the given string is `"aaaaabbbccc"` , the answer would be `["aaaaa","bbb","cc"]`, and I need to use the munch function to do this.

The condition of 9 characters applies too, so if the given string is `"aaaaaaaaaa"` , the answer would be `["aaaaaaaaa","a"]`

I've not actually got any implementation apart from something that I found which does pretty much does the same thing without the limit of 9 characters:

```
runs :: String -> String
runs x = group x
```

I thought of 2 ways of doing this, but I have no clue on the actual implementation, with one being to run the munch function for however many unique characters there are, i.e if there is an x amount of a , b , c in the given string, it would run 3 times, and then put those lists together into one list.

Another way that I thought of is to use guards. If the number of any single character in the given string is 9 or less, then just use the group function, otherwise, shorten it down using munch, or something like that.

Is anyone able to tell me if the two ideas I mentioned would work at all or suggest an alternative and how to get started? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: What is `chomp`? What does `munch` do?

Comment: Are you sure about that? How is `chomp` defined? Why do you have to use `munch`?

Comment: Your description of what `chomp` does is wrong.

Comment: "I need to use the `munch` function to do this." Assuming this is a homework assignment, and you were told you need to use the `munch` function, I doubt you'd get credit for using `group` instead. In that case, I would recursively use `munch` to pull off each chunk. You can then `drop` the `length` of the chunk to get the rest of the string, to recurse on.

Comment: @DarthFennec that makes sense. I think it's a similiar thing as to what I mentioned in one of the ideas I wrote in the post, but yours has more Haskell in it ;d

Answer (score 1):

here is another approach

define a split function to break list at fixed size chunks

```
splitn :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitn _ [] = []
splitn n x = take n x : (splitn n $ drop n x)
```

now you can write your function as

```
runs =  concatMap (splitn 9) . group
```

Comment: Can't you use `chunksOf` instead of `splitn`? They have identical signature.

Comment: @Elmex80s Yes of course, if I only remembered that it existed!

Answer (score 0):

A quick google gives you exactly what you're looking for.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158183/string-splitting-function-in-haskell

If it works consider upvoting their answer as I only copied a link

Answer (score 0):

The basic strategy here is to take each unique list element to identify successive list elements that are identical. This let you have list elements in any mixed order. There are three functions but no imports.

The first function is `rd` which creates the list of unique elements.

The second function, `t9` is because there might be over 18 of the same elements. `t9` will create 9 character long list segments of identical elements with the remainder as the last list (string).

The final, unnamed function uses `rd` to compile lists of all elements matching each unique elements. It uses `t9` to create segments of 9 elements.

```
l = "bbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaadddadaaaaaaacccccccccc"
rd [] = []; rd (x:xs) | elem x xs = rd xs | otherwise = x:rd xs
t9 [] = []; t9 xs = [take 9 xs] ++ t9 (drop 9 xs)
[ t | f <- rd l, s <- [[ g | g <- l, f == g ]], t <- t9 s ]
```

["bbbbbbbbb","dddd","aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaa","aa","ccccccccc","c"]